# Differential change in vector field components

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm reading 'Core Principles of Special and General Relativity' by Luscombe - the part on parallel transport.

> A vector $v$ given at every point of $\gamma(\lambda)$ with tangent vector $U^{\beta}$ is said to be parallel transported if the covariant derivative vanishes at all points of $\gamma(\lambda)$: $$U^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}v^{\alpha}=U^{\mu}(\partial_{\mu}v^{\alpha}+\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\ \ \rho\mu}v^{\rho})=0$$

I guess $U^{\beta}$ and $v$ are vector fields instead of vectors as claimed in the quote. Till here I can understand, but then it's written:

> Armed with the knowledge of parallel transport, we can complete the picture of the covariant derivative. **Let $\delta A^{\mu}\equiv -\Gamma^{\mu}_{\ \ \beta\nu}A^{\beta}\text{d}x^{\nu}$ denote the change in $A^{\mu}$ that occurs in parallel transport through $\text{d}x^{\nu}$ (see fig below).**
> [image]

I want to clarify my understanding of the part in bold. My current interpretation is: we can talk about the value of connection coefficients $\Gamma^{\mu}_{\ \ \beta\nu}$ *only in reference to some chart*, so let that chart be $(U,x)$.

Initially we consider a vector field $A$ with components $A^{\mu}$ and we start at some point $p\in U$ with coordinates $x^{\nu}$. The change in $A^{\mu}$, according to the text, is $-\Gamma^{\mu}_{\ \ \beta\nu}A^{\beta}(p)\text{d}x^{\nu}$.

But from parallel transport condition, we have $\partial_{\nu}A^{\mu}(p)=-\Gamma^{\mu}_{\ \ \beta\nu}A^{\beta}(p)$ and so, from what the book says, $$\begin{align}
\delta A^{\mu}\equiv\partial_{\nu}A^{\mu}(p)\ \text{d}x^{\nu}&=\text{d}A^{\mu}(p)
\end{align}$$

It seems like I can interpret the differential of $A^{\mu}$ at $p$, i.e. $\text{d}A^{\mu}(p)$ as the change in value of $A^{\mu}$ as I incrementally move from $p=x^{\nu}$ to $p'\equiv x^{\nu}+\text{d}x^{\nu}$.

My question is: **we can't assume the same interpretation for an arbitrary smooth function $f$, right?**

I ask this because " change in value of $A^{\mu}$ as I incrementally move from $p=x^{\nu}$ to $p'\equiv x^{\nu}+\text{d}x^{\nu}$ " seems like a coordinate-dependent quantity while $\text{d}f(p)$ is coordinate-independent.